# function names not displayed in gdb backtrace kgdb setup

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, gdb, remote-debugging, kgdb

I have set up a debugging environment of KGDB between two VMWare virtual machines using the following link:

https://embeddedguruji.blogspot.com/2018/12/debugging-linux-kernel-using-kgdb-part-1.html

When I run backtrace, I am not getting the function name. What I am missing here?

```
 Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0xffffffff9f141990 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0xffffffff9f141990 in ?? ()
#1  0xffffffff9f55d962 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000002 in irq_stack_union ()
#3  0xffffba8801a87f10 in ?? ()
#4  0x00000000017c4408 in ?? ()
#5  0xffffba8801a87f10 in ?? ()
#6  0xffffffff9f55ddb4 in ?? ()
#7  0xffff949d8a62f740 in ?? ()
#8  0xffffffff9f2cf5cc in ?? ()
#9  0x0000000001917000 in ?? ()
#10 0xffff949daf914400 in ?? ()
#11 0xffffffff9f25a066 in ?? ()
#12 0xffff949db7109ea0 in ?? ()
#13 0xffff949daf914400 in ?? ()
#14 0x0000000000000002 in irq_stack_union ()
#15 0xffffba8801a87f10 in ?? ()
#16 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: Are you compiling the kernel with debug flags turned on? on make menuconfig they are under _Kernel hacking > Compile-time checks and compiler options > Compile the kernel with debug info_.
Also, you did follow the note _Note: It is better to copy the whole linux build folder instead of just vmlinux to get source level debugging_ right?

Comment: Hi. I solved the problem, by adding nokaslr to the kernel command line